# security review payment needed every time a different package is submitted?

Tags: security-review

does every time I submit a package for review the review fee has to be paid? Or is it just once per year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app only needs to be reviewed annually, and any versions uploaded during the year are automatically marked as passed.

Comment: if I upload two packages under the same namespace. Does that mean, one single fee annually?

Comment: @oabarca It's per package, not per namespace. If you have two packages in the same namespace, you'll still have to pay for each package individually.